# How to get json output in php from url and get specific result using foreach

Tags: php

First of all I don't really know how to get the result of json which is so much complicated like this:

```
{
  "SearchTime": 190,
  "TotalTime": 190,
  "SuggestedResponseType": "Person",
  "ResultList": [
    {
      "__type": "ContactResult",
      "TotalCount": 57079,
      "Type": "Person",
      "Contacts": [
        {
          "UnitId": 459551,
          "Id": "459551S1",
          "Name": "John d",
          "VisitationAddress": "Lauvha 7, 87820",
          "PostAddress": null,
          "Value": "74 00 00 00",
          "ValueType": "Phone",
          "Distance": null,
          "Rank": 0,
          "BusinessName": null,
          "Coordinate": {
            "Lat": 64.4595741,
            "Lon": 11.55081
          },
          "Logo": null,
          "ContactPoints": [
            {
              "DisplayValue": "911 00 000",
              "Indent": 2,
              "Label": "Mobiltelefon",
              "MainInfo": false,
              "Type": "MobilePhone",
              "Value": "91000000"
            }
          ],
          "FirstName": null,
          "LastName": null,
          "OrganizationNumber": null,
          "Address": {
            "PostAddress": null,
            "StreetAddress": {
              "CityArea": null,
              "Coordinate": {
                "Lat": 94.4595741,
                "Lon": 71.55081
              },
              "County": "Tr\u00c3\u00b8ndelag",
              "DisplayValue": "Lauvha 7 87820 Spilm",
              "Entrance": "",
              "HouseNumber": "7",
              "Houses": null,
              "Municipal": "Namsos",
              "PostArea": "Spilm",
              "PostCode": "87820",
              "Street": "Lauvha"
            }
          },
          "Products": null,
          "ProfilePictures": null,
          "ContactType": "Person"
        },
        {
          "UnitId": 0,
          "Id": "Footer",
          "Name": "Vis flere treff",
          "VisitationAddress": null,
          "PostAddress": null,
          "Value": "{\"q\":\"john\",\"type\":\"p\",\"start\":1,\"page\":2}",
          "ValueType": null,
          "Distance": null,
          "Rank": 0,
          "BusinessName": null,
          "Coordinate": null,
          "Logo": null,
          "ContactPoints": null,
          "FirstName": null,
          "LastName": null,
          "OrganizationNumber": null,
          "Address": null,
          "Products": null,
          "ProfilePictures": null,
          "ContactType": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Stunts": null
}
```

Next: How can i get the output: name, VisitationAddress and value from (ContactPoints)to be in correct format using foreach

and rid the

```
"Name": "Vis flere treff",    
"Value": "{\"q\":\"john\",\"type\":\"p\",\"start\":1,\"page\":2}",
```

in the last line.

Comment: @C2486 No sir mine is more complicated

Comment: Please share your try with sample data?

Comment: @C2486 My apologies, i don't get your question?

Comment: Use json decode in php and share your tried code here what exactly you are getting as output ?

Comment: @C2486 I did not even try, cuz i know i couldn't make it :/

Comment: @C2486 Could you please help me out with this ? :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to read up on how to interact with objects and arrays in PHP.

`$object->property`, `$array['key']`, `$object->array_property[$index]->key`, etc.

For your particular case, you need to get your JSON using cURL or `file_get_contents()` or whatever other method you want. Then you need to decode the response with `json_decode()`.

Once you have your JSON object it's just a matter of checking to see if values exist and outputting them however you want. Notice there are a bunch of arrays inside objects, but something like the following will get you started

```
<?php

$response = file_get_contents( 'https://zabihullah.com/veg/example.json' );
//$response = '{"SearchTime":190,"TotalTime":190,"SuggestedResponseType":"Person","ResultList":[{"__type":"ContactResult","TotalCount":57079,"Type":"Person","Contacts":[{"UnitId":459551,"Id":"459551S1","Name":"John d","VisitationAddress":"Lauvha 7, 87820","PostAddress":null,"Value":"74 00 00 00","ValueType":"Phone","Distance":null,"Rank":0,"BusinessName":null,"Coordinate":{"Lat":64.4595741,"Lon":11.55081},"Logo":null,"ContactPoints":[{"DisplayValue":"911 00 000","Indent":2,"Label":"Mobiltelefon","MainInfo":false,"Type":"MobilePhone","Value":"91000000"}],"FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"OrganizationNumber":null,"Address":{"PostAddress":null,"StreetAddress":{"CityArea":null,"Coordinate":{"Lat":94.4595741,"Lon":71.55081},"County":"TrÃ¸ndelag","DisplayValue":"Lauvha 7 87820 Spilm","Entrance":"","HouseNumber":"7","Houses":null,"Municipal":"Namsos","PostArea":"Spilm","PostCode":"87820","Street":"Lauvha"}},"Products":null,"ProfilePictures":null,"ContactType":"Person"},{"UnitId":0,"Id":"Footer","Name":"Vis flere treff","VisitationAddress":null,"PostAddress":null,"Value":"{\"q\":\"john\",\"type\":\"p\",\"start\":1,\"page\":2}","ValueType":null,"Distance":null,"Rank":0,"BusinessName":null,"Coordinate":null,"Logo":null,"ContactPoints":null,"FirstName":null,"LastName":null,"OrganizationNumber":null,"Address":null,"Products":null,"ProfilePictures":null,"ContactType":null}]}],"Stunts":null}';

$json = json_decode( $response );

foreach( $json->ResultList[0]->Contacts as $contact ){
    //var_dump( $contact );

    if( $contact->Name == 'Vis flere treff' ) continue;

    if( !empty( $contact->Name ) ) echo "Name: {$contact->Name}\r\n";
    if( !empty( $contact->VisitationAddress ) ) echo "Address: {$contact->VisitationAddress}\r\n";
    if( !empty( $contact->Value ) ) echo "Value: ". str_replace(' ', '', $contact->Value) ."\r\n";

    echo "\r\n";
}
```

The result of that is the following:

```
Name: John d
Address: Lauvha 7, 87820
Value: 91000000

Name: Vis flere treff
```

You can see an example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad6aa7fffaf42a32cb8f5568acb24c157c612467

Comment: Thankyou so much and how can i rid "Name: Vis flere treff" ?

Comment: Hey, one more thing, when the result is more than it's not outputing: the Value: 91000000

Comment: To get rid of the Vis flere treff, you need to `continue` the loop. You can either do it based on that name, or some other value. For starters, underneath the `//var_dump( $contact );` line, you can put `if( $contact->Name == 'Vis flere treff' ) continue;` to skip that whole record and move on to the next.

Comment: I'd need to see more JSON to diagnose it not outputting the value, because the code, as written, will output the value if `$contact->ContactPoints[0]->Value` is not empty. You'll need to determine if you need to move the array pointer from `[0]` or any number of reasons really

Comment: You just need to determine what condition you want to remove Vis flere treff on - which apparently is Norwegian for "Show more hits"? I've updated the code [HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3201608941e960b903cd4308de99acf8e5def04b)

Comment: John Aksnes' value isn't showing up because his `$contact->ContactPoints` array is `null` - not an array like the other one

Comment: OR if there is some way to output without space {$contact->Value} ?

Comment: Anyway Thank you so much for helping me out.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you just want to remove spaces from `$contact->Value` - just use the `str_replace()` function. I've updated the code in the answer to reflect that

Comment: OK. i found an example of how to use the str_replace and i could make that one either ;/ https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_str_replace

Comment: Please don't hate me I'm just a new student  :)

Comment: No worries - we've all got to start somewhere! I meant I updated my answer above - but I moved it to a sandbox and you can see it working here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a9667e992c5a27c1e60f0d6b9ec68e90fa25b74

Comment: IDK HOW TO THX YOU ;) unbelievable helpful thankyouuuuu ;) i'll help somebody else one day just the way you do to me  :)

Comment: after watching, reading and learning i was wondering if there is a way to use str_replace() 2 times or more in one string. cuz in that api i want to hide some numbers and names. It worked with the single one :D

Comment: Good for you my friend! Yes there are a few ways to do it actually - nested functions, using an array instead of a variable, etc.

Here are a few examples: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5159a16174dd14ac288d8e66667129768b4b59af

Comment: you know what? i could make it this time. I'm happy just like a fat kid love cake :)

str_replace(array(' ', '12345678'), array('', 'no allowed!'),

Comment: Sorry for coming back to you. I've one more question for you.
When     if( $contact->Name == 'Vis flere treff' ) continue; is hidden and
if ( $contact->Name == 'Vis flere treff' ){ echo} is showing only what i want. 

Is it some how that i can use php get to search for example after something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your question. Currently if you remove the `if( $contact->Name == 'Vis flere treff' ) continue;`, you will output a line that says `Name: Vis flere treff`, do you want it to just say `Vis flere treff` with a link?

Comment: Here I've my code
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2f02c216f631d07e628adcb9b742259666b046c
 and i just want to know if i can use php get <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>
test.php?name=daisy

Comment: Please disregard that question. and check my code :) @Xhynk

Comment: did you get my question?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand the question. You can display if the `$_GET['name']` matches a result, like [This](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34ec006e8d8988583bf9cf1cc5e7d75fba0744bf) - is that what you want?

Comment: Yes something like this, you are very close. 
This is actually searching for name if i use test.php?name=Zabi
and what If for example search also for test.php?age=29 ?

I'm so thankful for you ;)

Comment: and sure If you please could replace this code for GET <?php echo isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'Zabi';?> that if for example the get is empty it should show output ZabiZabi

Comment: I'm not sure about the Zabi question but just replace the parameter names with the ones you're searching for, for instance the age thing: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c1957eb624d440aa2156a92ab5537365575b581

Comment: I think it's all becouse of my bad english :P trying the best i can to explain you, but i think i just should stop now. THANKYOU SO MUCH ;)

Comment: Right now I'm getting blank white page if I'm not using test.php?name=Zabi .. i thought i could use something like this if( isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'Zabi'){

Just to rid blank page. By adding this php function i may could have for exmple see all output both name and age. I HOPE YOU GET IT ;)

Comment: Check your error logs, or put `ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` and `error_reporting( E_ALL );` as the first and second lines of your file. They'll tell you what the error is

Comment: Please check it one more time:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a31eff4fdd2a95ad06f0912166b69cd24fb8ba85 

nothing is wrong with the code. working pefect, but only test.php?name=name given on browser

Comment: With that sandbox you can't send `$_GET` requests, you have to manually add in `$_GET['name'] = 'veronika';` - it's for testing purposes only. Adding that line of code below `$json = '{...` will simulate having `?name=veronika` in the address bar on a live site

Comment: I know. I test it on my website.

Comment: Mind sharing a link? Hard to get a read on the actual issue without seeing it first hand

Comment: You just need to handle non-existent `$_GET` parameters in a different way. Like `if( !isset( $_GET['name'] ) ) echo 'Please include a name in your search.';`

Comment: Aha, cuz i wanted to have on my index file where i want, when the user come inside it should show all both names and ages. as i can see there's no way :D THX

Comment: Oh I got it - that actually is possible, you just need another loop or to check inside the loop. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4eb5ec50e40e50076b36dd5871d3363a1e0a5a5